# How to improve performance of Query with new year of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL DB with 2 million rows of data. The query I have been using has been working fine, but then I added data for January 2019. For some reason, the query runs quickly on any other months, but when I try to extract information for just Jan 2019 it takes about an hour. Can anyone explain why it would perform worse for a new year and maybe provide a way to fix it? Would be incredibly helpful. I use:

```
Where Month([Posting Date]) = 1 and Year([Posting Date]) = 2019
```

to extract it with the query.

Comment: Maybe you should check your indexing? Also show the actual execution plan in SSMS and see if that makes a suggestion.

Comment: An hour to fetch rows from a table with 2 million rows is highly suspicious.  That is just too much time.  Something else is going on.

Comment: First, this might need to be moved to dba.stackexchange. Second, it might help if you could provide the full Select statement and the table's definition (including indexes).

Comment: Instead of the where month and year, have you tried Where [Posting Date] between '2019-01-01' and '2019-02-01'

Comment: What is the datatype of `[Posting Date]`? Also, doing filtering of this many rows based on date functions would definitely benefit from a Calendar Table.

Answer (score 1):

You may be a victim of parameter sniffing. SQL Server thinks it is using an appropriate index when it isn't. Try ending the query with OPTION   (RECOMPILE)

To really see what is going on you would have to show us the query plan.